# Проектирование клиент сервера

Tags: mysql, rest, клиент-сервер, проектирование, мобильная-разработка

Начиная проектирование нового проекта (моб. приложение) встретил задачу с который хотел посоветоваться с вами. Есть клиент андроид. Есть сервер. Общение REST запросами. Так вот в базе данных есть вопросы (очень много может быть). При запросе клиента нужно выдать случайный вопрос из базы данных. При этом при повторном запросе следующий вопрос повторятся не должен (т.е. каждому клиент вопрос один раз посылается). Вопрос как это реализовать? Есть идея на клиент устройстве id каждого вопроса сохранять и при запросе к серверу отправлять список id и уже на сервере на основе этого списка выдавать вопрос. Мне кажется идея какая то мутная. А если человек прошел 250-400 вопросов это все отправлять это ведь трафик и как то ресурса затратно. Можете что нибудь посоветовать?

Comment: Передавать вопросы клиенту значит не затратно, а передать id (число) - это сразу космический трафик. Сервер при выдаче вопросу клиенту, должен сохранять уже отправленные этому клиенты вопросы

Comment: Хешами итераций общайтесь, как индексом, будет вам экономия трафика. А по сути, надо поискать готовые транспортные решения, удовлетворяющие вашим требованиям, их полно..

Answer (score 0):

Просто мысль.. Если на сервере хранить, например, тысячу детерминированных сценариев.. Клиенту присвоить случайным образом ИД сценария. И на сервер можно отправлять ИД сценария и ИД последнего вопроса. Должно быть менее объемно, чем хранение связки "ИД вопроса <-> ИД клиента", если клиентов больше тысячи (например).

Comment: неплохая идея. Подумать нужно о реализации